# Parse Search more than 100 Queries

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I wrote a search function with Parse and I am trying to get more than 100 results. I have added the query.limit(1000) but the search is still only getting results 100 and below.

The serach works with user input and as a user inputs values the table below the search box updates and displays the values.

```
function userSearch(searchValue) {

        $('body').addClass('loading');
        /*Users Per Country*/


        $('#user-pagination tbody tr').remove();

        /*Run Parse Query*/
        var firstName = new Parse.Query("User");
        firstName.limit(1000);
        firstName.contains("first_name", searchValue);


        var lastName = new Parse.Query("User");
        lastName.limit(1000);
        lastName.contains("last_name", searchValue);


        var userEmail = new Parse.Query("User");
        userEmail.limit(1000);
        userEmail.contains("email", searchValue);

        var mainQuery = new Parse.Query.or(lastName, firstName, userEmail);
        mainQuery.limit(1000);

        /*Prepare Parse Query*/
        mainQuery.ascending("last_name");

        mainQuery.find().then(function(results) {
            console.log(results.length);
            if (results.length === 0) {
                endOfResults = "true"
                z = parseInt(z) - 10;
                $('body').removeClass('loading');
                $('#next-user').addClass('disabled');
            } else {
                $('body').removeClass('loading');
                $('#pagination').hide();
                $('#user-pagination tbody tr').remove();
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    var object = results[i];

                    var blockStatus = object.get('suspended');
                    if (blockStatus === "1") {
                        blockClass = "unBlockUser";
                        blockText = "Unblock"
                    } else {
                        blockClass = "blockUser";
                        blockText = "Block"
                    };

                    $('#user-pagination tbody').append('<tr><td><a data-object="' + object.id + '" href="' + siteUrl + '/app-users-page/?user=' + object.id + '&blocked=' + blockText + '"">' + object.get('last_name') + '</a></td><td>' + object.get('first_name') + '</td><td>' + object.get('email') + '</td><td><a data-object="' + object.id + '" href="#" class="updatePin">Reset PIN</a> | <a data-object="' + object.id + '" href="#" data-mail="' + object.get('email') + '" data-name="' + object.get('first_name') + ' ' + object.get('last_name') + '" class="' + blockClass + '">' + blockText + '</a> | <a data-object="' + object.id + '" href="#" class="delete-user">Delete</a></td></tr>');
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually working, it seemed that Parse.com cached the 100 queries. I am going to leave this here as there are not many examples of Parse.com javascript search functions.